Proper equivalence of quadratic forms preserves direct composition (in the sense of Gauss)
This is exercise 3.5(c) of Cox's Primes of the Form $x^2+ny^2$. The question is (paraphrased):

Question: Suppose $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are (integral) binary quadratic forms and $F(x,y)$ is the direct composition of $f$ and $g$. If $\tilde f$ is properly equivalent to $f$, then $F$ is also the direct composition of $\tilde f$ and $g$.

Definitions:
I'll use "form" to mean integral binary quadratic form.

Two forms $f(x,y)$ and $\tilde f(x,y)$ are properly equivalent if $\tilde f(x,y) = f(rx+sy,tx+uy)$, where $r,s,t,u\in \Bbb Z$ and $ru-st = +1$.


If $f$, $g$ and $F$ are primitive (no common divisor of coefficients) positive definite forms of the same negative determinant, then $F$ is a composition of $f$ and $g$ if $$f(x,y)g(z,w) = F(B_1(x,y,z,w), B_2(x,y,z,w)),$$
where $$B_i(x,y,z,w) = a_ixz + b_ixw + c_iyz + d_iyw$$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$. It follows that $a_1b_2 - a_2b_1 = \pm f(1,0)$ and $a_1c_2 - a_2c_1 = \pm g(1,0)$. If both signs are '$+$', then $F$ is a direct composition of $f$ and $g$ (in the sense of Gauss).

Solution attempt:
Below is my best attempt, but I feel I've hit a dead end. Maybe some determinant shenanigans imply that the relevant expressions below must have the same sign, or something? My gut feeling is that some symmetry argument should be fairly obvious, but I'm stuck...
Let $f(x,y)=ax^2+byx+cy^2$, $g(x,y)=a'x^2+b'yx+c'y^2$ and $F(x,y) = Ax^2+Byx+Cy^2$. Let $\tilde f(x,y) = f(rx+sy, tx+uy)$. We can write $$
B_i(x,y,z,w) = 
\begin{pmatrix}z\\w\end{pmatrix}^T
\begin{pmatrix}a_i&c_i\\ b_i&d_i\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}
=: 
\begin{pmatrix}z\\w\end{pmatrix}^T
X_i 
\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix},
$$
and thus
$$
\tilde f(x,y)\cdot g(z,w) = f(rx+sy, tx+uy)\cdot g(z,w)
= F\left(
\begin{pmatrix}z\\w\end{pmatrix}^T
X_1
\begin{pmatrix}r&s\\ t&u\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}z\\w\end{pmatrix}^T
X_2
\begin{pmatrix}r&s\\ t&u\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}
\right).
$$
So $F$ is a composition of $\tilde f$ and $g$, and we must show that it is direct. Multiplying out the inner matrices and simplifying, this reduces to two equations to prove:
$$
g(1,0) = (a_1c_2 - a_2c_1)(ru-st),
$$
which is obviously true, and
$$
\tilde f(1,0) = f(r,t) = (a_1b_2 - b_2a_1)r^2 + (a_1d_2-a_2d_1-b_1c_2+b_2c_1)rt + (c_1d_2 - c_2d_1)t^2.
$$
If we can prove that the three expressions in brackets are $a$, $b$ and $c$ respectively, we would be done.
$a_1b_2 - b_2a_1 = a$ by assumption.
$c_1d_2 - c_2d_1 = \pm c$ by a symmetry argument: $F$ is also the composition of $f'(x,y):=f(y,x)$ and $g$, which gives "inner matrices"
$$
X'_i = X_i \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}c_i&a_i\\ d_i&b_i\end{pmatrix}.
$$
However, can we conclude that it must be $+c$ rather than $-c$? I can't see how to do it.
Assuming that indeed it is $+c$ above, we can do a similar trick for the middle coefficient. With $f'(x,y) := f(x+y,x)$, we get
$$
X'_i = X_i \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}a_i+c_i&a_i\\ b_i+d_i&b_i\end{pmatrix}.
$$
This yields
$$\begin{split}
\pm(a+b+c) 
&= \pm f(1,1) \\
&= \pm f'(1,0)  \\
&= (a_1+c_1)(b_2+d_2) - (a_2+c_2)(b_1+d_1) \\
&= (a_1b_2 - a_2b_1) + (a_1d_2-a_2d_1-b_1c_2+b_2c_1) + (c_1d_2 - c_2d_1) \\
&= a + (a_1d_2-a_2d_1-b_1c_2+b_2c_1) + c.
\end{split}$$
Again, to finish this line of reasoning, I would need the first $\pm$ to be a $+$, from which it would follow that the bracketed expression is equal to $b$ as desired...

I've found a solution by looking in the original source, Gauss' Disquisitiones Arithmeticae §235. It's not very enlightening at all, or particularly elegant, so I'll only give an outline. I do wonder if there really isn't a better way to proceed....
Define for brevity $P_{ab} = a_1b_2 - b_2a_1$, $P_{ac} = a_1c_2 - c_2a_1$, etc. Furthermore, let $d$, $d'$, $D$ be the discriminants of $f$, $g$ and $F$ respectively, i.e. $d=b^2-4ac$ and so on. By assumption, $d=d'=D$.
The result will follow from these two general identities (recall that $a = P_{ab}$ by assumption in our case):
$$ \tag{1}
ab = P_{ab}(P_{ad} - P_{bc}),
$$
$$ \tag{2}
ac = P_{ab}P_{cd}.
$$
From the main equation $f(x,y)g(z,w) = F(B_1(x,y,z,w), B_2(x,y,z,w))$, by substituting $x,y,z,w$ by $0$ or $1$ in suitable combinations, it's straightforward to write any product of one of $a,b,c$ and one of $a',b',c'$ in terms of $A,B,C,a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i$ (where $i=1,2$). We get:
$$\begin{split}
aa' &= Aa_1^2+Ba_1a_2+Ca_2^2 \\
ab' &= 2Aa_1b_1 + B(a_1b_2 + a_2b_1) + 2Ca_2b_2 \\
ac' &= Ab_1^2+Bb_1b_2+Cb_2^2 \\
ca' &= Ad_1^2 + Bd_1d_2 + Cd_2^2 \\
&\vdots
\end{split}$$
and so on, for a total of nine such identities. From these, it follows that
$$
abd' = ab'\cdot bb' - 2aa'\cdot bc'-2ac'\cdot ba' = DP_{ab}(P_{ad} - P_{bc}).
$$
Recalling that $d'=D$, this proves $(1)$. (Incidentally, $a=\pm P_{ab}$ can be seen similarly).
For $(2)$, it gets significantly more complicated. Define
$$
\Delta = 2A(a_1d_1 - b_1c_1) + B(a_1d_2 + a_2d_1 - b_1c_2 - b_2c_1) + 2C(a_2d_2 - b_2c_2).
$$
(Note that you get the expression for $bb'$ if all minuses above are changed to plusses). We can then verify that
$$
4acd' = b^2d' - dd' = (bb')^2 - 4ba'\cdot bc' - dd' = 4DP_{ab}P_{cd} + (\Delta^2 - dd').
$$
The final step is to show that in fact $\Delta^2 = dd'$, which I will not include here. Gauss shows it by combining six different identies similar to the ones above, yielding two identies containing $\Delta^2 - dd'$, and from which it follows that $\Delta^2 - dd'=0$. He also mentions in a footnote that it can alternatively be shown directly from the first list of identies ($aa'$, $ab'$, etc.), that $(\Delta^2 - dd')^2=0$.
